# JQuery - which .js do I need to download just to use the 'toggle' functionality?

Tags: jquery

What's the minimum JavaScript I need if all I want to do is use the JQuery toggle functionality?

I'm confused if I need to download everything from

http://jqueryui.com/download

Or if I can use just the base JQuery from jquery.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) you simply need regular [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is is the base JQuery. In other words, just [this file](http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [jQuery](http://jquery.com) itself.

You only need jQuery UI if you want to use one of its [UI components or effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).